# Reference System.Data in Visual Studio 2015 UNITY project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, mono

I'm using Visual Studio for my Unity project. (Unity is using mono framework, NOT .net). I'm using a database so I have to use System.Data.dll in the project which i'm keeping in Assets/Plugins folder:

[image]

As you can see Visual Studio has problems seeing System.Data library. So I'm hardcoding:

[image]

---

And some more red lines:

[image]

Surprisingly, I have no errors in Unity and the code is actually working:

[image]

I also have this annoying yellow icon in VS:

[image]

Can you help me in forcing Visual Studio to see System.Data library please?

Comment: Inside your unity installation folder there should be a system.data. Replace the one in your project, with the one in your installation folder Path probably looks something similar to: `C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\unity`

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's the library I'm using, I've re-imported it just in case but still the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *System.Data.dll*, *System.MySql.dll* and *System.Drawing.dll* should all placed in the *Assets* folder not in the *Assets/Plugin* folder. Making these changes get ride of the error.

**EDIT**:

Adding *System.Data.dll* to the *Assets* folder should work but is failing silently. Digging deeper into this, I got this error:

> The primary reference "System.Data" could not be resolved because it
>   has a higher version "2.0.5.0" than exists in the current target
>   framework. The version found in the current target framework is
>   "2.0.0.0".

So, the *System.Data.dll* version is different from your target framework and that is the problem. You need another version of *System.Data.dll* that is the-same version of your target framework(2.0.0.0).

You can get a compatible version(2.0.0.0) from:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v3.5\Profile\Unity Subset
>   v3.5

Comment: Thanks @Programmer but it's still same :( strangely the _System.MySql.dll_ and _System.Drawing.dll_ seem fine. It's just _System.Data.dll_ that's bumping my OCD spikes

Comment: Even though it might be fine, they should *all* be placed at Assets folder. Where did you get those DLL's? I want to try it

Comment: the _System.Drawing.dll_ and _System.MySql.dll_ are from some Unity forum thread, I was playing with mysql and came across the thread. But the System.Data.dll is from here:
C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\unity

Comment: on mac: /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono/lib/mono/2.0

Comment: Ok. Will take a look. Why do you need to access database directly from your app? Do you plan to release this to the public and are you connecting to a server with database?

Comment: of course not, I'll probably get an ec2 instance on amazon but for now I'm just curious

Comment: For 2018.2.2+ it seems that Mono/lib no longer exists on Mac?

Comment: @ina Answered your other question.