# Unity 2018.2.10f1 Mac - Missing System.Data, System.Data.odbc for accessing .accdb

Tags: macos, ms-access, unity-game-engine, mono

Trying to use .accdb [(via this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906303/odbc-connection-to-an-accdb-file)) in Unity 2018.2.2+ (upgraded to .10f1 just now, but same issues still occurring).

`The type or namespace name Odbc' does not exist in the namespace System.Data'. Are you missing an assembly reference?`

`The type System.Data.DataTable' has been forwarded to an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'`

Where does one find the missing .dll's for System.Data, System.Data.odbc, System.Data.DataTable etc on Mac?

Note: have tried the other results at [Reference System.Data in Visual Studio 2015 UNITY project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40399362/reference-system-data-in-visual-studio-2015-unity-project) and others. The new directory for mono no longer seems to contain those .dll's? `/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoBleedingEdge/MonoEmbedRuntime/osx` seems to only have 3 .dylibs https://gyazo.com/d7222ee65635db6394be000605739759

Answer (score 0):

This directory seems to be changing over time. It's currently the `XXX.MonoBleedingEdge/lib/mono` folder. You can find the `System.Data.dll` in these directories:

On Mac:

```
/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoBleedingEdge/lib/mono/2.0
```

On Windows:

```
<UnityInstallationDirectory>\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\2.0-api
```

There should be different .NET dll version folders in the `/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/MonoBleedingEdge/lib/mono` or `<UnityInstallationDirectory>\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono` but the `2.0` or `2.0-api` folder seems to be fine if you are using the *".NET 3.5"* in the Editor. If you are using anything above it, make sure to use the correct folder (Usually the `4.5` folder for *".NET 4.x"* option in the Editor).

Remember to put them in the `<ProjectName>\Assets\Plugins` folder.

Comment: For 2018.2.2f1 and .10f1 - that folder only contains 3 dylib's ... https://gyazo.com/d7222ee65635db6394be000605739759 ... i don't see System.Data.dll - or am i just not understanding how to use these dylib's as dll's?

https://gyazo.com/85c28bf9255e27f7a74aaf5d6d76214a

Comment: That's weird. There should be a folder named "lib" under "MonoBleedingEdge". Run the installer again then download "Mac Build Support (Mono)"

Comment: Seems to have moved out of Frameworks folder - just under `../Contents/Mono/lib/mono/`...

Comment: Ok. If you find the folder, just copy the `System.Data.dll` from there

Comment: Next error: `System.DllNotFoundException: Dependency unixODBC with minimum version 2.3.1 is required.` ... ugh

Comment: And... System.Data.Odbc isn't in that directory

Comment: You wan want to use `System.Data.SQLClient` over `System.Data.Odbc` as that's what is supported in Unity.

Comment: That then yields this error: `error CS0234: The type or namespace name `SQLClient' does not exist in the namespace `System.Data'. Are you missing an assembly reference?`

Comment: Also, I am trying to access the .accdb which requires ODBC... though i could convert that somehow to sql*? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764707/sql-connection-string-for-microsoft-access-2010-accdb

Comment: For your SQLClient error, you also need `System.Data.SqlClient.dll`. As for .accdb, that's for Microsoft Windows specific stuff and Unity did not include that.  The fact that you're trying to use it on a Mac will make it more complicated than ever. What are the names of folders in the `Mono/lib/mono` folder? Can you show a screenshot? Also, where did you get the current `System.Data.dll` you're using?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/f15733a108c36a14850cbdd9289f4b9a Grabbed the System.Data.* files here

Comment: Which db conversion would you recommend for Unity iOS apps

Comment: I don't even know what you're doing to begin with and can't recommend. What are you doing? You need to store data on a remove/network server or you just need to do it locally on the device?

Comment: Just read/query data locally from a large USDA Nutritions database - they provide the entire thing as an .accdb  https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/nutrients/index

Comment: The screenshot you posted is what's in `Mono/lib/mono` folder?

Comment: yes, the screenshot directory is on the bottom part of he screenshot https://gyazo.com/c3e41c15dd3dddd109888b7a20c84fe6